# Create Custom Dialog Box using dispatch events,states and titlewindow in flex/AS3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

Since a month Iam working on creating a custom dialog box, having parameters like message,state and modal(true/false)

Eg:

```
showAlert("Hi, how are you doing","Goodmorning", true);
```

I have learned how to dispatch event. but unable to dispatch the alertevent/popupManager using States.
Below is the code, I am struggling with.

Main.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
 <mx:Script>
<![CDATA[

    public function onclick(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
    this.dispatchEvent("Hi, How are you?", "Morning", true);
    }
     public function dispatchEvent(arg1:String, arg2:String, arg3:Boolean):void
    {
        var str:*=null;
        str.message = arg1;
        str.stateName = arg2;
        str.modal = arg3;
        this.dispatchEvent(new ShowAlert(ShowAlert.SHOW, true));
    }

]]>
  </mx:Script>  
  <mx:Button id="click" click="onclick(event)"/>
  </mx:Application>
```

ShowAlert.as

```
package 
{
import flash.events.*;

public class ShowAlert extends Event
{

    public var _stateName:String;

    public var _closable:Boolean;

    public var _message:String;

    public var _isModal:Boolean;
    public static const SHOW:String="show";


    public function flash.events.(arg1:String, arg2:Boolean=false, arg3:Boolean=false)
    {
        super(arg1, arg2, arg3);
        trace("arg1: "+arg1+"\t arg2: "+arg2+"\t arg3: "+arg3);

    }

    public function set message(arg1:String):void
    {
        this._message = arg1;

    }


    public function get message():String
    {
        return _message;
    }


    public function get modal():Boolean
    {
        return _isModal;
    }


    public function get stateName():String
    {
        return _stateName;
    }

    public function set stateName(arg1:String):void
    {
        this._stateName = arg1;

    }




          public function set modal(arg1:Boolean):void
    {
        this._isModal = arg1;

    }

    public override function clone():flash.events.Event
    {
        return new ShowAlert(type);
    }


 }
 }
```

I was unable to write the custom titlewindow using states, so I dint post that.

### Please let me know, how to make this happen.

Below is the Sample code, specifying my problem

main.mxml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
 <mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
import mx.controls.Alert;
public var info:IModuleInfo;
public var loadalert:DisplayObject;
import mx.modules.ModuleManager;
    import mx.modules.IModuleInfo;
    import mx.events.ModuleEvent;
    public function init():void
    {
        Alert.show("This is forst alert.");

    }
    public function Loadalerrt():void
    {
        trace("loadalertmodule");
        info = ModuleManager.getModule("../bin-debug/alerrtmod.swf");
        info.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, modEventHandler); 
        info.load();

    }
    public function modEventHandler(event:ModuleEvent):void
    {
        trace("modeventHandler");
    loadalert=info.factory.create() as DisplayObject;
    can1.addChild(loadalert);

    }
]]>
 </mx:Script>
<mx:Button label="Alert in Application" id="b1" click="init()" x="29" y="21"/>
<mx:Button label="Load Module" id="b2" click="Loadalerrt();" x="10" y="92"/>
<mx:Canvas id="can1"  x="409" y="57" backgroundColor="cyan"/>
</mx:Application>
```

alerttmod.mxml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="400"   height="300">
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
import mx.controls.Alert;
    public function alertshow():void
    {
        Alert.show("This is second alert, You Can see it covers whole   application, What I want is its scope should be limited to this specific module, not to whole application ");
    }
]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Button label="Alert in Module" id="b1" click="alertshow()" x="163" y="100"/>
</mx:Module>
```

Comment: I think you need to be more specific in your question. Which scenario do you want to achieve? Why is there no MXML code in your "Panel.mxml"? It seems to be an AS code, does not it? What is "SlertAlert"?

Comment: Hi Anton,
My Fault. I have modified the code.

Comment: Hi @Anton,  
My Fault. I have modified the code.  
Here what i am actually looking for is, a custom alert/pop-up box, should be restricted to individual module.(Default alert box has global scope, it covers whole application area.). I need to create a alertbox whose scope is local to module, and should not affect to whole application.  

The Panels.mxml is a simple component, to be used as alertbox(with text and buttons).  

I hope , my explanation make sense to my actual problem. Any help is appreciated.  
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by saing about global and local "scope" in your situation? Could you give a real example from your task, where the normal alertbox has an unwanted behaviour? Is it about the way to init, to show or to get the result of a dialog? Sorry if I don't understand you correct.

Comment: Hi @Anton,  I have added a sample code, to my question. Please view the output of that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I see your problem. I think it is not possible to restrict the modal area of the Alert. I can suggest you to fake the modal behaviour by desabling the modules elements while your dialog is being shown.

May be it can help you...

Here are two components to demonstrate it:

//your module with another Alert

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="400"   height="300">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

        public function alertshow():void
        {
            Alert.show("This is second alert...");
        }

        public function alertshow2():void
        {
            var customAlert:CustomAlert = new CustomAlert();
            customAlert.addEventListener("CLOSED", onCustomAlertClosed);
            this.enabled = false;

            PopUpManager.addPopUp(customAlert, this, false);
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(customAlert);
        }

        private function onCustomAlertClosed(evt:Event):void
        {
            this.enabled = true;
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Button label="Alert in Module" id="b1" click="alertshow()" x="163" y="100"/>

<mx:Button label="CustomAlert in Module" id="b2" click="alertshow2()" x="163" y="150"/>

<mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="0xbbbbbb" alpha="0.8" visible="{!this.enabled}"/>

</mx:Module>
```

//simple CustomAlert as a Panel

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Panel xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="300" height="200">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
            this.dispatchEvent(new Event("CLOSED"));
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Button x="112" y="128" label="Close" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</mx:Panel>
```

Comment: One last question, can we decrease the alpha value of background, by other means, because, when i am reducing the alpha value of the module (using `this.alpha=0`), each and every component in module is getting effected.

Comment: Would you like to change the alpha value of background only or should it look something like the grey blur area of the Alert component?

Comment: You could use a Canvas over the whole Module, which is visible if the Module is disabled. I have added this line into my example. (<mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="0xbbbbbb" alpha="0.8" visible="{!this.enabled}"/>)

Comment: I want to change the complete alpha value to 0, , how the output should look like is, the component(alert box) is just added to the module, it should not make the background blur or something. Thanks